# WingIDE -- Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python

Suppose I have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed. 
In WingIDE 101, how do I choose whether I am using Python 2 or Python 3?

For example, I was currently working with python 3 and now I need to use the image module which is only supported in python 2. How do I change it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

there is a python icon on the interface .click and change